# Is Adobe XD or Figma important in front-end development

Tags: html, css, frontend, adobe-xd

Currently, I'm studying front-end development and I saw a lot of web developers building their websites on adobe XD before starting building it using HTML and CSS. I want to know how can adobe XD be used in web design and is it worth learning or a time waste?

Comment: XD is for designers primarily - it does however give you the css printouts so you can get your project looking exactly like the design. Whether it's worth learning, I'd say it completely depends on what you're looking at doing, if it's just front-end web development then I'd say no - but if you're wanting to be a hybrid of a designer & developer then yes.

Answer (score 3):

Figma and Adobe XD provides you an END GOAL to your website's front-end. They are usually done by designing team and not by developers. We developers just take reference from it and build our website accordingly.
It's not much needed to learn if you're a developer, but if you learn it then it would add to your skill of grasping UI more easily and transform that Figma/Adobe XD page into actual code.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it is important, with Figma and Adobe XD you can build an animated prototype for your clients in few minutes without the hassle of dealing with code. In practice you can focus exclusively in the UX/UI side of the App/Website you are working on.